# How do I pattern match on array size in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I want to write a function to return the sum of all numbers divisible by 3 in a given list. I don't know how to pattern match on the size of a list. I get a nil pointer exception when I run the following code.

I am trying to do this using first principles, instead of using `loop` `map` and `reduce`

```
(defn sum3
  [[head & tail]]
  (if (= (mod head 3) 0)
    (+ head (sum3 tail))
    (sum3 tail))
  [[head]]
  (if (= (mod head 3) 0)
    head
    0))


(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println (sum3 [1 2 3])))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function dispatch in clojure is done on the number of arguments to the function **and not on the number of destructured values** in the function call.

Once the appropriate arity has been selected, and the function has started running, the destructuring occurs and binds the symbols to the desctructured values.

Fortunatly clojure offers arbitrary custom function dispatch in the form of [multimethods](http://clojure.org/reference/multimethods) so if you want to dispatch based on the length of the arguments you can. For your example it's overkill though not particularly hard. There are other cases where it makes sense.

A normal, single arity, approach to this function would look like this:

```
user> (defn sum3
       [[head & tail]]
       (if (seq tail)
         (if (= (mod head 3) 0)
           (+ head (sum3 tail))
           (sum3 tail))
         (if (= (mod head 3) 0)
           head
           0)))
#'user/sum3
user> (sum3 [1 2 3 4 5 6])
9
```

You should in general always use recur rather than direct recursion though for this question it's not too much of an issue when demonstrating this principal .

Comment: `(sum3 ())` is a problem for this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

First let's do the version using `reduce`:

```
(defn sum3 [coll]
  (reduce (fn [sum el]
            (if (zero? (mod el 3))
              (+ sum el)
              sum)) 0 coll))
```

Notice the use of `zero?`. No need for pattern-matching here.

Then we can go on to use recursivity:

```
(defn sum3
  ([coll] (sum3 0 coll))
  ([sum [head & tail]]
   (let [add (if (zero? (mod head 3))
               (+ sum head)
               sum)]
     (if tail
       (recur add tail)
       add))))
```

Again, no pattern matching (you would have to use `core.match` for that  -clojure does not use pattern matching). The dispatch is only made using the number of arguments. This is why your function was not valid syntax: it was in both cases a 1-arity function. Note the use of `recur` to recurse the function. It can only be used for tail-recursion.

We could make it a 1-arity function without dispatching on arguments as well:

```
(defn sum3
  [[head & tail]]
  (let [m3? (zero? (mod head 3))]
    (if (seq tail)
      (if m3?
        (+ head (sum3 tail))
        (sum3 tail))
      (if m3? head 0))))
```

Note that this version is not tail-recursive and will overflow for big inputs.

But really the `reduce` version - or even the `loop` version look much better.

Answer (score 0):

in fact the main error is in the `defn` syntax. You don't define two arities here, rather make one arity `[[head]]` and then goes the body, which is totally valid clojure code. To make 2 arities you should put each into brackets:

```
(defn sum3
  ([[head]]
   (if (= (mod head 3) 0)
     head
     0))
  ([[head & tail]]
   (if (= (mod head 3) 0)
     (+ head (sum3 tail))
     (sum3 tail))))
```

but it would also fail
because you don't define different arities, they are equal (one argument call), so the compiler would produce an error. Clojure destructuring is not pattern matching at all. It is just a way of retrieving items from a collection. But you can fix this (emulate kind of length pattern matching) with a minor change:

```
user> 
(defn sum3
  ([head]
   (if (= (mod head 3) 0)
     head
     0))
  ([head & tail]
   (if (= (mod head 3) 0)
     (+ head (apply sum3 tail))
     (apply sum3 tail))))
#'user/sum3

user> (sum3 1 2 3 4 5 6)
9

user> (apply sum3 [1 2 3 4 5 6])
9
```

now you have fair variant with two different arities.

But yes, it is not tail recursive, so in real life you would go with `reduce` or `loop/recur`